# populating values in excel using java - excel has primary key values

Tags: java, excel

I am trying to populate an excel file which has names. I am quering a database and need to update excel values based on the names. I am having issues as I think the values get overwritten and only the last value is stored in the text.

I am iterating the resultset and check for the name in the excel. If they match, I am populating the values.

My code is below - Apologies for lot of SOPs

```
public class ExcelWriteDB {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try
    {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection connection2 = null;
        // Create a connection to the database
        connection2 = DriverManager.getConnection("");
        Statement mystat2 = connection2.createStatement();

        String query = "";

        ResultSet result = mystat2.executeQuery(query); 

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd2=result.getMetaData();

        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("source.xlsx"));

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(2);


        while(result.next()){

        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

        while (rowIterator.hasNext())
        {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            //For each row, iterate through all the columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

            Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
            Cell cell3 = row.createCell(2);

            if (cell != null) {

            switch (cell.getCellType())
            {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    if(cell.getStringCellValue().equals(result.getString("NAME"))){
                        double UPB = Double.parseDouble(result.getString("UPB"));

                        cell3.setCellValue(UPB);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            }
        }



        }// while(result.next()){

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("ZXC.xlsx"));
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();

        file.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

I am sure I am missing something, but I am not sure what. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you arent doing anything in the first `Case` of the `switch` statement. Is that correct?
Secondly, you arent iterating on your `cellIterator` at all. You always get the 0th cell. Also, you arent writing to the file at all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

 - SWITCH here is just place holder, I will add more logic later.

 - The logic is to check the name in the first column of each row, that is why I am iterating through each row and getting the first column. Also based on the names, I need to find the values of the names in the resultset. So everytime I need to get the first column and update in the 3rd column(more columns later).

 - I am writing in a file below after iterating through all the DB resultset.

The issue is the results are ok, just only the last row is getting updated. 

Thanks again.

Comment: I got this working. It was an error in logic, had the add the following logic
 Cell cell3 =  row.getCell(2);
                if(cell3 == null) {
                   cell3 =row.createCell(2);
                }

instead of just creating the cell every iteration. Thanks again for the help.